# Where is Apple Appcenter

Tags: certificate, push

I'm trying to renew the iOS push certificates according to this link
https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.HOWTO95536.html

Tutorial says "In the AppCenter console, go to Settings --> Certificates --> Apple/iOS Certificates."

O_o I'm looking for this "appcenter console" since 2 hours...
Where is the "AppCenter console" 
I looked into the itunesconnect page of my app, not found, neither in the apple developer portal..

Answer (score 1):

Apple does not have an AppCenter. [AppCenter](https://appcenter.ms) is a distribution/analytic/push-notification/etc. service offered by Microsoft for mobile development.